# How to add multiple if loop results to a single JOptionPane message dialog?

Tags: java, if-statement, joptionpane, messagedialog

I'm super new to all of this but I'm trying to figure out how to get all the following results (which are now shown in separate message dialogs following each other) into a single message dialog window.

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "De prijs per persoon is  €" + part + ".");

    if (fnum > part){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, fname + " krijgt  €" + (fnum - part) + " terug.");
    }
    else if (fnum < part) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, fname + " moet nog  €" + (part - fnum) + " betalen.");
    }
    else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, fname + " heeft alles betaald.");
    }


    if (snum > part){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sname + " krijgt  €" + (snum - part) + " terug.");
    }
    else if (snum < part) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sname + " moet nog  €" + (part - snum) + " betalen.");
    }
    else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sname + " heeft alles betaald.");
    }


    if (tnum > part){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, tname + " krijgt  €" + (tnum - part) + " terug.");
    }
    else if (tnum < part) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, tname + " moet nog  €" + (part - tnum) + " betalen.");
    }
    else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, tname + " heeft alles betaald.");
    }
```

Comment: Instead of making an OptionPane in each loop, only make a string in each one. Then after they are all done, create a single OptionPane with the string you just created.

Comment: @Takendarkk Oh, wow. Thanks! I have one follow up question though if you don't mind. I made a string for each line (fstring, sstring & tstring) but how can I put them under each other in the OptionPane window? I did this:  
  
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "De prijs per persoon is  €" + part + "." + fstring + sstring + tstring);  
  
But that puts them next to each other in a long line.

Comment: Try something like this `"De prijs per persoon is €" + part + "." + fstring + "\n" + sstring + "\n" + tstring);` I have added `"\n"` inbetween your string variables. This is what is called a newline character. Not sure if it will work, but it is easy for you to try. If it all works out for you let me know and I will type out an answer for you that you can accept.

Comment: @Takendarkk That worked beautifully!

Comment: @Takendarkk Of course, least I can do! (:

Comment: Good luck to you. Happy coding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating a `JOptionPane` inside of each if statement, you only need a single one at the end. Your if statements are really only determining what string to display, so that's the only info you need to create inside them. You can do this by creating a string variable and determining what it contains in the if statements. Then, once your statements have executed, you create a single `JOptionPane` with your string included. For example:

```
String temp;

if (fnum > part) {
    temp = fname + " krijgt  €" + (fnum - part) + " terug.";
}
else if (fnum < part) {
    temp = fname + " moet nog  €" + (part - fnum) + " betalen.";
}
else {
    temp = fname + " heeft alles betaald.";
}

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, temp);
```

As per your comments - If you want strings to be placed on multiple lines you can add a `"\n"` character to your string anywhere you want it to move to a new line.